# Submitting dynamically added forms (MVC app)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that contains a partial view, which has dynamically added form fields (name and date-range for each guest). How do I submit all these fields to a post method, so that I get a list of all the guests (name AND date-range)?

The partial view:

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ViewModels.GuestCreatorViewModel
@using Res = ProjectName.Resources.Resources

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.NumOfGuests; i++)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label(Res.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label(Res.Period, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateRange, new { id = "dateRangePicker", @class = "form-control custom-date-picker", @readonly = true })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRange, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="@Res.CreateGuests" class="customBtnXSmall" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input.custom-date-picker').daterangepicker({
            "showWeekNumbers": true
        }, function (start, end, label) {
            console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
        });
    </script>
```

I'm guessing that I can write some javascript or an AJAX function to post the information, since it's just strings, but I'm not sure how and I'm not that skilled with javascript.

Can anyone help me make a simple post action for these dynamic form fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually really simple, and already implemented. I already used model binding to bind the data to a model, so instead of the model having "name" and "daterange" attributes as `string`, I just changed their type to `List<string>` and that way it fills all the values into those lists.

```
public ActionResult CreateGuests([Bind(Include = "Name,DateRange,NumOfGuests")] GuestCreatorViewModel viewModel)
```

```
public List<string> Name { get; set; }
public List<string> DateRange { get; set; }
```